# How to update Chromedriver on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, selenium-chromedriver

I want to update Chromedriver to the latest version.

How can I do this on the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download chromedriver from `https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/chromedriver_linux64.zip`

Unzip it and put it in location `/usr/bin/chromedriver` and change its permission to 755 using chmod.

Answer (score 63):

#### Download Chrome for Testing (Version 115 and later)

Google now releases "Chrome for Testing"

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

If you need a new version, download it from here

#### Download Chromedriver (Version 114 and before)

This should download the old-school version of Chromedriver, and extract it to the correct location, with the correct permissions.

```
version=$(curl -s "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE")
wget -qP /tmp/ "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${version}/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
sudo unzip -o /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /usr/bin
```

The permissions should be `755` by default, but if they aren't, you can run:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

If you want a specific version, see the [index page](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html), or the [website](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/).
You can also edit the above commands to use `LATEST_RELEASE_80`, if you wanted version 80, for example.

---

#### Update to latest Chrome

If you don't already have the latest version of Google Chrome, you may need to update it with:

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Then use this to update Chrome: `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable`

Comment: This HAS to be the accepted answer.. the fact that you don't have to hunt chromium webpages to get the link or version number, and not having to download and unzip and move stuff manually is very nice.

Comment: This does not give you the latest version on Ubuntu 20, I got 93.0 something where as the latest is 95 today.

Comment: I guess Google forgot to update the `LATEST_RELEASE` file. If you want a specific version, I also included instructions for that. They'll probably fix their problem in a week or two.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable`

Comment: This may not work for version 115 and later because of changes in the way releases are made. https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 12):

```
$ wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/chromedriver_linux64.zip
$ unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
$ sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
$ sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Comment: Don't forget to update the 2.35 to reflect the version you want to download!

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers got the `LATEST_RELEASE` that is 114, however that is not compatible with the current latest chrome version 116. (both versions correct to the time of the answer of course).

To download the right `chromedriver` version:

1. Go to https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
   (got there from https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/?pli=1)
2. Choose the version according to your OS and chrome version and copy that link.
   [image: chromedrivers versions on googlechromelabs site]
3. install it (using the link you copied above)

```
wget -qP /tmp/ "<the-link-you-copied...>"
sudo unzip -oj /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /usr/bin
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

4. check it:

```
chromedriver --version
```

Comment: This worked for me, just replace:
`chromedriver_linux64.zip` with 
`chromedriver-linux64.zip`

Answer (score 1):

After version 115, due to changes in the way ChromeDriver is released, the most accepted Addison's answer may no longer work. The currently working Eran's answer has been changed to automate the versioning process. This eliminates the need to visit the release page.

```bash
version=$(curl -s "https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE")
echo "Installing ChromeDriver for version $version"
wget -N https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/${version}/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip -O /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip
sudo unzip -oj /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip -d /usr/bin
```

```bash
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/chromedriver
chromedriver --version
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this for chromium:
Find your chromium Version here:

```
chromium-browser --version
```

Find the corresponding chromedriver Verion here:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Then install as per MatzFans instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up using a downloaded independent Chromedriver. I'm using the Chromedriver that comes together with Chromium. This way they will always be in sync and (to answer the exact question) to update the chromedriver it's just necessary to update the Chromium version.

I've installed Chromium with snap:

`snap install chromium`

If I run:

`snap info chromium`

I see there are two commands, one for browser and the other for chromedriver:

```
commands:
 - chromium.chromedriver
 - chromium
```

All I have to do is run it, in my case I want to use port 4444:

`chromium.chromedriver --port=4444`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check the Version of Chromium.

```
chromium-browser --version
```

Easiest way would be to download the `Driver` you need as per above chromium version then drop in `/usr/share/bin` directory in `Linux`.

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads (to download  Driver needed)

```
sudo mv -v <location_downloaded_driver>/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/.
```

To make sure `Chrome Driver` is properly working, you may check the version you just installed as below:

```
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver -v  #prints you the installed version
```