# Delete chromedriver from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

I want to update the version of chromedriver that I installed following this instruction https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/

To do this, I want to delete the current version. I tried to do this by finding the desired folders with the

> whereis chromedriver

command. 
And deleting the files from there using rm. But

> chromedriver -v

still gives the value of the old version. What is another way to completely remove the current chromedriver?
Also i tried just update following this topic [How to update Chromedriver on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649230/how-to-update-chromedriver-on-ubuntu)
But chromedriver -v still return old version

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're positive you've already removed it using:

`sudo rm -f /usr/bin/chromedriver`

And you say that `chromedriver -v` is still printing output, then try running `which chromedriver` again, and `rm`ing the file until it returns nothing.

You might need to delete files at:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
sudo rm -f /usr/local/share/chromedriver
```

---

If you want to go on a rampage and delete every instance of it, even those that are not on your path, you can try finding all instances of it using:

```
locate chromedriver
```

or (may take a long time)

```
find / -name "chromedriver"
```

and remove those.