# When refreshing the page Selenium.WebdriverTimeoutException : Timeout receiving message from renderer: 3000 with new Chrome 103 versions in Specflow

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running my automation in VM and Chrome version gets automatically updated. Now my VM chrome version is 103.0.5060.114(64-bit).

However, my Selenium chrome driver version is 103.0.5060.5300 which is the latest one in Nuget. Problem is I can't downgrade chrome browser. I use `driver.navigate().refresh()` method which was working fine a month ago.

Recently I tried different ways of refreshing and added disabling gpu still having the issue. Not sure if Chrome and/or Selenium is aware of that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

*Chrome Version 103.0.5060.114* is the most updated version and well supported by *ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.53 (2022-06-22)*. So all seems well from configuration per se.

As per the [ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.53 (2022-06-22)](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/103.0.5060.53/notes.txt) release notes:

> Supports Chrome version 103

Comment: I didn't have this problem until recent time. Now once I switch back from second URL to first and update to see changes, I get timeout exception. I haven't had that issue a month ago. And haven't had any changes in my scripts. It never failed. Chrome has zero day vulnerability, and I am positive that new version has some issues.

Answer (score 0):

**I downgraded Chrome from *103.0.5060.114-1* to *103.0.5060.53-1* on Ubuntu like so:**

- 1st — uninstall the current Chrome via: `sudo apt remove google-chrome-stable`
- 2nd — install the deb binary file of the chrome that you want to have:

E.g.

```
 wget "https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_{VERSION}_amd64.deb"
 sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_{VERSION}_amd64.deb
```

---

**Particularly, what I entered into the command line to downgrade:**

```
sudo apt remove google-chrome-stable
wget "https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_103.0.5060.53-1_amd64.deb"
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_103.0.5060.53-1_amd64.deb
```

---

Some resources I used when I was looking for the answer for myself:

- [How to update Chromedriver on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649230/how-to-update-chromedriver-on-ubuntu)
- https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable
- https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/how-can-you-install-google-browser-debian

---

If you are using some other system, I assume the approach would be the same.
I hope all of this would help you!

Comment: Thanks, Aleksei for your comment and tips. I am running my VS from VM and not allowed to downgrade or change things. And my company didn't want to downgrade it because of some security engineering team's concerns. I will try to run these commands. Much appreciate!