# confusion on which chrome driver to use for latest google-chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-18.04, google-chrome-headless

i have a EC2 instance running on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. On this server, i regularly use selenium to perform some automated website testing -- i open chrome in headless mode and have selenium to make it perform some actions. I wish to upgrade both `chrome-driver` (currently on `ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90`) and `google-chrome` (currently on `Google Chrome 115.0.5790.110`) versions due to some recently discovered vulnerabilities. I see that `google-chrome`'s latest stable version is 120.0.6099.109, however the `chrome-driver` seems to still be 114 and according to their [download page](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection), they are pointing me to a [chrome-for-testing](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) repo to download the latest chrome-driver. I dont think i would want a testing version, i want to use the latest chrome-driver that is compatible with the latest stable version of google-chrome. Am i mis-understanding here or is the wording just confusing?

As an example, [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649230/how-to-update-chromedriver-on-ubuntu/57306360#57306360) are the instructions i roughly follow on updating these two pieces of software

Comment: They moved things to support the built-in chromedrivermanager stuff.  You'd just use those URLs to download the latest.  ("Stable" versions are not betas... those are the current releases.)

Comment: or, just let Selenium do the work for you... if you don't specify a browser binary or driver path, it'll automatically download and use them.  (re-downloading and updating when necessary)  That'd be as simple as initializing the driver like " WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();" https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/#automated-driver-management